# maximum boolean array size to open compute shader?

Tags: shader, gpgpu, gpu

Does 1000 cubic voxel in gpgpu shader, 1bn booleans, use up about one gygabite of memory?

The Resource limits pages don't state any index limits to 2d and 3d arrays in GPU's. Are they theoretically in the thousands or in the trillions?

Comment: I found that a GLSL bool is in terms of uniform blocks, it has the same size as uint: 32-bits. perhaps it has been optimized since glsl 3.7

Answer (score 0):

for compute capability>=3.0 the max grid dimensions are 2147483647x65535x65535,
so for a that should cover any 1-D array of sizes up to 2147483647x1024 = 2.1990233e+12.

I have used arrays of 1 billion are no problem.

1,000,000,000/1024=976562.5, and round up to 976563 blocks... if threadIdx.x+blockIdx.x*blockDim.x>= number of elements you return from kernel without processing.